# Checking arguments in python

Tags: python-3.x, arguments

Hello I am a noobie programmer who just started coding.
Suppose a function exists:

```py
def ask(a,b,c):
```

So how can I return a string if the user doesn't give 3 arguments while calling the function?
for example:
`ask(1,2)`
or `ask(1,2,3,4)`?

Comment: Do you want the function to return a string, or do you want the call to result in an exception?  The latter is already the default behavior.

Comment: i want to return "WRONG NUMBER OF ARGS" if the number of argument doesnt match

Comment: Python will do that for you,  Experiment.  Or use `def ask(*args):` and do your own checking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can a variable number of arguments when defining the function.

```
def ask(*args):
  if len(args) != 3
    return "WRONG NUMBER OF ARGS"
  a, b, c = args
  # use a, b, c.
```

Answer (score 0):

If you simply want to  do it for a regular function you can do something like this:

```py
def ask(a, b=None, c=None):
    if(b is None or c is None):
        return 'Error!'
    return 'Ok'

def ask2(*a):
    if(len(a) !=3):
        return 'Error!'
    return 'Ok'

print('---- ASK 1 -------')
print(ask(1,2,3)) //OK
print(ask(1,2)) //Error
print(ask(1)) //Error

print('\n---- ASK 2 -------')
print(ask2(1,2,3,4)) //Error
print(ask2(1,2,3)) //Ok
print(ask2(1,2)) //Error
print(ask2(1)) //Error
```

Here I defined 2 kinds of `ask`, the first one gets at most 3 arguments and at least one.

The second one used `*` that can get a set of numbers with any number of items, then inside the method, we check if the length of the set is exactly 3(with the help of `len`).

But if you want to use this function for python arguments for command-line interfaces, there is a better way to do that, [check here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html) for more detail.

```py
import argparse

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='Process some integers.')
parser.add_argument('integers', metavar='N', type=int, nargs='+',
                    help='an integer for the accumulator')
parser.add_argument('--sum', dest='accumulate', action='store_const',
                    const=sum, default=max,
                    help='sum the integers (default: find the max)')

args = parser.parse_args()
print(args.accumulate(args.integers))
```

With the help of `argparse`, you can force the user to enter exactly the number of arguments you need to start your program also you can define optional arguments for command that users can use and etc.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed solution but I had completed the task with the reference  of  Alex's solution above :D

Comment: That's totally OK, StackOverflow isn't a one only ask/answer question for only one person and just for once. I started answering after you had accepted Alex's.